# Is it possible to disable logging for Android.Vibrator?

Tags: android

I have a game that uses vibration for tactile feedback. It works fine but on some devices each time the Vibrate API is called it results in the following lines added to the logs:

> 03-16 17:05:42.000 7458 7490 V Vibrator: Called vibrate(long) API!
>
> 03-16 17:05:42.000 7458 7490 V Vibrator: vibrate(long,
> AudioAttributes) API - PUID: 10299, PackageName: com.xyz.xyz, ms: 14,
> AudioAttr: null
>
> 03-16 17:05:42.000 7458 7490 V Vibrator: Called
> vibrate(int, String, long, AudioAttributes) API - PUID: 10299,
> PackageName: com.xyz.xyz
>
> 03-16 17:05:42.000 7458 7490 V Vibrator:
> vibrate - PUID: 10299, PackageName: com.xyz.xyz, ms: 14, AudioAttr:
> null, mag: -1

I am worried this much writing to the log might affect performance (this is a game after all), so is there a way to disable this automatic logging? Note that this doesn't happen on every devices, only some.

Comment: "so is there a way to disable this automatic logging?" -- not in general. Are those messages being logged from your process, or from a core OS process?

Comment: The logged lines show up in the game logs, so my guess is that it is from some thread running under the same PID that the game. However it is not the game itself or a compiled library that does the logging as it doesn't happen on all devices. Basically, it looks like some phone ship with a flag that tells them to log calls to the Vibrate API.